# Function for priority queue in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, priority-queue

Is there a library in ocaml with which I could make a priority queue and handle it?

I have checked this "http://holgerarnold.net/software/ocaml/doc/base/PriorityQueue.Make.html"
but it does not have anywhere an example of how to use these commands.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a slightly larger tutorial for Core's heap.

```
open Core.Std

(* A heap only expects a comparsion function on its elements. Use
  polymorphic compare if you just want something tham makes sense most
  of the time *)

let pq = Heap.create compare

let reverse_pq = Heap.create ~min_size:10 (Fn.flip compare)

(* The optional min size argument is there for optimization purposes. If you
   know that your heap will grow past a certain size you can allocate the array
   of that size in advance to save copying/resizing later on since the heap is
   array based *)

let () = 
  let random_list = List.init 10 ~f:(fun _ -> Random.int 10) in
  (* core wraps values inserted into the heap in the type 'el heap_el
    where 'el is the type of elements in your heap *)
  let heap_el = Heap.push pq (Random.int 10) in
  (* this gives you O(1) existence check in the heap: *)
  let x = Heap.heap_el_mem pq heap_el in (* true in O(1) *)
  let value_in_el = Heap.heap_el_get_el heap_el in
  (* now standard heap stuff, insert a list into a heap *)
  random_list |> List.iter ~f:(Fn.compose ignore (Heap.push pq));
  (* now drain the heap and get a list in sorted order, for reverse
  order you'd us reverse_pq *)
  let sorted_list = 
    let rec loop acc =
      match Heap.pop pq with
      | None -> acc
      | Some e -> loop (e::acc)
    in loop [] in
  printf "Sorted: %s\n" 
    (Sexp.to_string_hum (List.sexp_of_t Int.sexp_of_t sorted_list))
```

Don't hesitate to use Core. It will make your OCaml much more pleasant. More questions are always welcome.

Answer (score 7):

OCaml Batteries included has a polymorphic priority queue in the module named [BatHeap](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatHeap.html). You can use it just by adding elements to the empty heap, and so on.

Jane Stree Core has a fancier looking priority queue in the module named [Heap](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Heap.html).

**Update:**

The Heap of Jane Stree Core is indeed fancy. One way to describe it is that there are two interfaces to a heap. The first interface is as a collection of ordered values whose least element can be located in constant time and removed in log time. The second interface considers a heap to be a collection of containers ("heap elements") with ordered values in them. If you're willing to deal with these containers explicitly, some of the heap operations can be performed more quickly.

Here is an extremely simple example that uses a heap (the first interface) to sort a list:

```
let heapsort l =
    let heap = Core.Std.Heap.create compare in
    List.iter (fun x -> ignore (Core.Std.Heap.push heap x)) l;
    let rec extract () =
        match Core.Std.Heap.pop heap with
        | None -> []
        | Some x -> x :: extract ()
    in
    extract ()
```

(This code is somewhat artificial; it's just showing how to put values into a heap and get them back out.)

Here's an example of running this code (in an OCaml toplevel with Core support):

```
# #use "sort.ml";;
val heapsort : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# heapsort [3;1;4;1;5;9];;
- : int list = [1; 1; 3; 4; 5; 9]
#
```

Comment: I've checked them and it would be really useful If I knew how to use them. I'm new in ocaml and I need a demonstration to figure out how to use "create" for example. When I read val create : ?min_size:int -> ('el -> 'el -> int) -> 'el t

create ?min_size cmp, I can understand what "create" does but not how (by how I mean what operands it gets an how I call it).

Comment: I am installing Jane Street Core right now, but unfortunately I won't be able to make an example for you until after dinner. There are many other Core users out there who might be able to help sooner :-).

Comment: Thanks for your help! The one thing I don't understand is how would I know to write Core.Std.Heap.create by reading this "val create : ?min_size:int -> ('el -> 'el -> int) -> 'el t

create ?min_size cmp". Is there something I have to read to understand this sort of things easier?

Answer (score 6):

The chapter [The module system](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html) of the OCaml manual starts with a code example implementing a priority queue. This is my go-to implementation of priority queues, and as the whole implementation fits in 25 lines it is easy to use and understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to add to this code two more function. One which can find a specific element and one which can remove it. I try to make it happen but I experience  some short of problems.

Comment: This link is now broken

Comment: thanks @rgrinberg, I put a link that should be more permanent.